# Issue naming worksheets after cell range

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to use the cell values (text) in cells O2:O29 to create worksheets. When I run the macro, it creates one new worksheet for each of the colors but does not name them accordingly. My goal is to have them named accordingly.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sheets("specifiedsheet").Select
Range("A1").Select
Dim cell As Range

Dim color As Range
Set color = Sheets("specifiedsheet").Range("O2:O29")

For Each cell In color
    On Error Resume Next
        Sheets.Add.Name = cell.Value
Next cell
```

FYI, the data in column O is a list of colors.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
Dim sourceSheet as Worksheet
Dim newSheet as Worksheet
Dim sourceRange as Range
Dim cell As Range

Set sourceSheet = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("specifiedsheet")
Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("O2:O29")

For Each cell In sourceSheet.Cells
    Set newSheet = Thisworkbook.Sheets.Add
    newSheet.Name = cell.Value
Next cell
```

Let me know if it works